# How to get JSDoc autocomplete to work for a function returned by another function with spread arguments?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm centralizing user-facing message string templates in a Node API I'm writing so all my strings live together.  I'd like to be able to build these strings dynamically from elsewhere in the code by passing a template function the arguments it needs to build the message, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to structure JSDoc to perform autocompletion for the object that's passed to my "string builders", AKA the functions returned from `template` below.  See below for an example of what this would ideally look like.  You can mostly ignore the `template` function implementation as it's taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates.

```
// strings.js

// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates
function template(strings, ...keys) {
  return function(...values) {
    var dict = values[values.length - 1] || {};
    var result = [strings[0]];
    keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
      var value = Number.isInteger(key) ? values[key] : dict[key];
      result.push(value, strings[i + 1]);
    });
    return result.join('');
  };
}

/**
 * Returns a string for welcoming mentees to the platform.
 * @param {object} params
 * @param {string} params.name The name of the mentee.
 */
export const menteeOnboardingWelcome = template`Hi ${'name'}, welcome!`;

/**
 * Returns a string for when a mentee and mentor are matched.
 * @param {object} params
 * @param {string} params.menteeName The name of the mentee.
 * @param {string} params.mentorName The name of the mentor.
 */
export const menteeMentorMatched = template`${'menteeName'} and ${'mentorName'} have been matched!`;

console.log(menteeMentorMatched({ menteeName: 'Jack', mentorName: 'Jill' }));
```

When typing that last line, I'd like autocomplete (in VSCode, if that's helpful) to list `menteeName` and `mentorName` plus their associated documentation, but since `template` returns a function that takes in `...values` that's what it shows instead.  How can I structure my JSDoc to show what I want instead of `...values`?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dTuG.png)

Another option, of course, is to simply wrap the string builder functions in a function wrapper for documentation:

```
export const menteeMentorMatched = ({ menteeName, mentorName }) => `...`
```

I suspect this is the only way to make JSDoc work in this case.  While this wouldn't be too bad, it's just a little more verbose than I'd like it to be since I'd like to avoid as much bloat as humanly possible in this file.